# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect sql database.
What am I doing wrong? Please help

### constants.php

```
<php
// Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "1234");
define("DB_NAME", "widget_corp");
?>
```

---

### connection.php

```
<?php
require("constants.php");
//1. Create a database connection 
$connection = mysql_connect('DB_SERVER','DB_USER','DB_PASS');
if(!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

//2. Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db('DB_NAME', $connection);
if(!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

---

Comment: Is that really `<php` or a typo?  Need `<?php`.

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your `constants.php` file seems to have a typo in the opening PHP tag. You should update the file as follows:

```
<?php
// Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "1234");
define("DB_NAME", "widget_corp");
?>
```

Secondly, constant names aren't strings, they're constants. Your `mysql_connect()` function should look like this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

And similarly, `mysql_select_db()` should be:

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
```

You should be advised though, that the `mysql_*()` family of function is now deprecated. You should consider using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for security and longevity.

Answer (score 1):

You've quoted your constants:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('DB_SERVER','DB_USER','DB_PASS');
                            ^--       ^-^--- etc...
```

Once quoted, they're no longer constants - they're strings that happen to have contents that share the name of a constant. So you're literally trying to connect to a server named `DB_SERVER`, instead of the server named `localhost`. Try without quotes:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
```

Answer (score 0):

constants.php line 1.

```
<?php //And not <php, this isn't HTML.
```

Answer (score 0):

@AbraCadaver is correct that the constants.php file should start with `<?php` not `<php`.

You also need to remove the single quotes when using your constants.

Lines:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('DB_SERVER','DB_USER','DB_PASS');

$db_select = mysql_select_db('DB_NAME', $connection);
```

Should be:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
```